# Linked Implementation of Queues in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have written a function `Serve` to get the front node in the queue and remove it. It is as follows:

```
void Serve(QueueNode **p,Queue *q)
{
    if(QueueEmpty(q))
        Error("Queue is empty!");
    else
    {
        if(q->front==q->rear)
        {
            *p=q->front;
            q->front=q->rear=NULL;
        }
        else{
            *p=(q->front);
            q->front=q->front->next;
            (*p)->next=NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

I call it from the main function as follows:

```
int main() {
    QueueNode **p=malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
    Queue *q=CreateQueue();
    Append('a',q);
    Append('b',q);
    Append('c',q);
    Append('d',q);
    Serve(p,q);
}
```

While declaring the pointer to pointer `QueueNode`, if I set it to NULL or leave it uninitialized the program gave me NULL pointer dereference or accessing wrong memory location. I can understand why. But, here, when I create the `QueueNode` using `malloc` in this line:

```
QueueNode **p=malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));
```

the space allocated is getting wasted when I reassign it to `q->front` in the `Serve` function. How can I save this space. Also, I just need a pointer that points to `q->front`. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry I need a pointer that points to q->front !

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. The `malloc()` probably isn't needed **at all**, but no way to be sure without having a self-contained example.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That leaks a `QueueNode`. There is no need to malloc a node. It should be `QueueNode* p = NULL`.

Comment: @Banex what is `nullptr`? You mean `NULL`?

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yes, sorry, got confused by C++.

Comment: @Banex Ah, sure. I will delete my comment.

Comment: `QueueNode **p=malloc(sizeof(QueueNode));` this is wrong, no matter what. It should be `sizeof(QueueNode *)` or better just `sizeof *p`. But then, as I already said, I don't see why you're allocating memory here **at all**.

Comment: Abd he is not feeing it either :0

Comment: @FelixPalmen Because it was not allowing me to access it from serve in line *p=q->front because here it was uninitialized !

Comment: @FelixPalmen As already pointed out by Banex, `QueueNode *p = NULL;`...`Serve(&p, q);` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need allocate memory for `p`. it's already allocated in function `Append()`.

```
int main() {
    QueueNode *p=NULL; 
    Queue *q=CreateQueue(); 
    Append('a',q); 
    Append('b',q); 
    Append('c',q); 
    Append('d',q); 
    Serve(&p,q); 
}
```